# Hooks for mac, specifically keyboard hooks

Tags: macos, keyboard-hook

I have recently been trying to make a keylogger for macs (since I work on one) JUST FOR FUN, no intent to use it. I have literally been looking around for 10+ hours and have found zero documentation of hooks for macs. Could anyone point me in the right direction?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Intercept keyboard input in OSX](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3806256/intercept-keyboard-input-in-osx)

Comment: Next time, you might want to post a bit sooner :-)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Keyboard input on OSX](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4809251/keyboard-input-on-osx).

Answer (score 2):

Make a KEXT and load it up!

http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Darwin/Conceptual/KernelProgramming/About/About.html

Might need to read a good bit of this...

http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/DeviceDrivers/Conceptual/IOKitFundamentals/Introduction/Introduction.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP0000011-CH204-TPXREF101

Lots of overhead involved if you aren't up to speed.

If you want to get right to it, there was a good phrack article on osx rootkits an issue back...

http://www.phrack.com/issues.html?issue=66&id=16#article