# Overriding main.m with run loop but still getting to the NSApplicationMain call?

Tags: objective-c, c, xcode

Apologies if this is a stupid/easy question, but still getting used to everything in Mac land.

Dave was kind enough to answer a question for me here:
[Modify NSEvent to send a different key than the one that was pressed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5785630/modify-nsevent-to-send-a-different-key-than-the-one-that-was-pressed)

which resulted in the following code, which works great:

```
#import <Cocoa/Cocoa.h>

CGEventRef myCGEventCallback(CGEventTapProxy proxy, CGEventType type, CGEventRef event, void *refcon) {
    //0x0b is the virtual keycode for "b"
    //0x09 is the virtual keycode for "v"
    if (CGEventGetIntegerValueField(event, kCGKeyboardEventKeycode) == 0x0B) {
        CGEventSetIntegerValueField(event, kCGKeyboardEventKeycode, 0x09);
    }

    return event;
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    //return NSApplicationMain(argc, (const char **)argv);

    NSAutoreleasePool * pool = [[NSAutoreleasePool alloc] init];
    CFRunLoopSourceRef runLoopSource;

    CFMachPortRef eventTap = CGEventTapCreate(kCGHIDEventTap, kCGHeadInsertEventTap, kCGEventTapOptionDefault, kCGEventMaskForAllEvents, myCGEventCallback, NULL);

    if (!eventTap) {
        NSLog(@"Couldn't create event tap!");
        exit(1);
    }

    runLoopSource = CFMachPortCreateRunLoopSource(kCFAllocatorDefault, eventTap, 0);

    CFRunLoopAddSource(CFRunLoopGetCurrent(), runLoopSource, kCFRunLoopCommonModes);

    CGEventTapEnable(eventTap, true);

    CFRunLoopRun();

    CFRelease(eventTap);
    CFRelease(runLoopSource);
    [pool release];

    exit(0);
}
```

Thanks to some helpful error messages (can't have two "main" methods) I figured out that I had to put this code in the `main.m` file (right?). That means I'm overwriting the default method:

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    return NSApplicationMain(argc, (const char **)argv);
}
```

Which means none of my other Objective-C based code is firing. But if I uncomment that bit (or make any other attempt to call NSApplicationMain) then the `main.m` run loop is what doesn't run.

I imagine this is fairly simple for a seasoned Mac guy, but I'm having a hard time wrapping my head around it. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't see any reason why the same idea won't work elsewhere in your code.  Can you put it in the `-applicationDidFinishLaunching:` method of your app delegate?  If you do, you will not need the `CFRunLoop()` call, since the run loop will already be running.  Nor will you need the autorelease pool bit.