# Intercept function-key strokes on Mac

Tags: cocoa, cgeventtap

I want to intercept function-key strokes in MacOS, not F*x* keys, but specifically Volume Up/Down and Mute.

Obviously, this should be done in a global way, not only when my program is frontmost.

I read this can be achieved using a [CGEventTap](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5785630/modify-nsevent-to-send-a-different-key-than-the-one-that-was-pressed/5785895#5785895), but it requires either root priviledges or *assistive devices access* to be enabled for the application.

VLC does this with Back/Playback/Next function-keys, if it is playing it completely overrides iTunes control.
*And it does it without being root or even having assistive devices access enabled.*

Any idea?

Comment: Search for "media keys". Also, VLC is open source.

Comment: @KenThomases Yes, I know it, one way I considered is in fact inspecting VLC sources. But before, I just want to know if Volume keys could be considered like Media keys, or if they are more "system-level" (and therefore not overridable).